# Android YouTube API ads

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have incorporated YouTube API in my app to play various videos but all the videos which normally show ads, do not show those ads in my app.

Does the YouTube API support showing video ads?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they do play ads. Both the player API and the [player SDK](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) supports ads. You even have functions like onAdStarted() etc

Comment: I've seen and read all of the docs but in practice it's not working. I play a video on YouTube app and it shows with ads. I play those same videos in my app (which uses YouTube player API) but no ads show up.

Comment: How can I get controls over ad played by the youtube player api